# How to prevent changing the screen when using "this.props.navigation.navigate"?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'd like to pass the values from Tab to another Tab and I follow instructions from this tutorial https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html

I got the values at the end but i don't want to change the screen suddenly.

I tried to use 'setParams' instead but it doesn't work.

Setting tab (Selection) :

```
onPress={() => {
     console.log('Select : '+ item.code);
     this.props.navigation.navigate('A-page', {adCode: item.code});
}}
```

First tab (A-page) :

```
this.setState ({
     AirportCode : this.props.navigation.getParam('adCode','----')
})
```

Any ideas for passing values across Tab navigation or method to stop changing the screen suddenly?

Comment: Maybe what you want is more on the state/props level with multi-level component, and changing component based on state instead of navigate the navigation.

Comment: that's new thing for me let me try. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks more like a Redux use case then a React Navigation one. If you wanna change properties that influence more than one screen in your app, you should store these properties at the redux store.

Comment: I still have to use this property as normal. So, any ideas for passing value across Tab navigation?